# How to make 2d gravity using JavaScript?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

So I'm making this 2d space game where the player controls a moon and the faster the moon spins the faster the objects fall. So the question is how can I make objects fall at the rate of the moon. Hope this is detailed enough.

This is what I have for the moon control:

```
var mGravity:int=1;
var mGravityMax:int=63;
var mGravityMin:int=1;
var speedDamp:float=0.5;
private var speedDampV:float;

function Start () {


}

function Update () {

    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * mGravity);

    if(Input.GetKeyDown("1"))
      if(mGravity == mGravityMin)
        Debug.Log("Lowest Spped!");

        else 
            mGravity = Mathf.SmoothDamp(mGravity,mGravityMin,speedDampV,speedDamp);
            Debug.Log(mGravity);

    if(Input.GetKeyDown("2"))
      if(mGravity == mGravityMax)
        Debug.Log("Max Speed!");

        else
            mGravity = Mathf.SmoothDamp(mGravity,mGravityMax,speedDampV,speedDamp);
            Debug.Log(mGravity);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spinning an object will not increase its gravitational force.

You have a misunderstanding between artificial gravity and gravity. Artificial gravity is the centripetal force from acceleration, which only applies to objects in the system. That means, that if you are on the moon you would feel the Acceleration, but if you are above the moon you would not, so you would not be more attracted to it because it's spinning faster.

Therefore your game is not realistic so you can come up with your own equation. For example:

```
F = a_rot/2;
```

Then apply that force to the object that your moon is attracting.